# ignore compiler warning from one file in Google Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm using an external library (Phonegap) in a fairly large Closure project. Unfortunately Phonegap generates a ton was compiler warnings (all "dangerous use of this"). Enough that it makes searching through the compiler output for warning about my own code pretty annoying.

Is there a way to silence just the warnings from one file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you mean type warnings when you are using VERBOSE or checkTypes.

Put the following into any file:

```
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @suppress {checkTypes}
 */
```

to turn off type checking *for that file only*.  You can `@suppress` many other things as well.  Read the Closure Compiler docs for more details.

### Dangerous use of "this"

However, if you are talking about "dangerous use of this" warnings, **DO NOT** ignore them.  They refer to places where:

1. You have a namespace
2. You defined a function within that namespace
3. You use "this" inside that function -- and this can refer to the namespace
4. That namespace may be *flattened* by the compiler

For example:

```
foo.bar.hello = "Hello World!";
foo.bar.baz = function() {
   alert(this.hello);
};
foo.bar.baz();    // this --> foo.bar
```

The "alert" statment will be flagged by a compiler warning of "dangerous use of this".  Why?  Remember, if the compiler *flattens* the "foo.bar" namespace:

```
$foo$bar$hello$ = "Hello World!";
$foo$bar$baz$ = function() { alert(this.$hello$); }
$foo$bar$baz$();   // this --> window
```

Notice I am using debug variables renaming here.  In reality, "$foo$bar$baz" may be renamed just to "a".

You can see immediately that the call to `foo.bar.baz()` will fail because "this" no longer refers to "foo.bar", but refers to the global object.  You code will crash with a loud **CRANK!**

### Exception cases when "this" is OK

Now, there are cases where usage of "this" is OK.  For example, in event handlers.  "this" will automatically point to the DOM node that raised that event.

In these cases, you need to use the following type of JsDoc directive:

```
/** @this {Node} */
```

to specify the type expected for "this" in order to shut the compiler up.

Comment: Oops.  @defrex, I didn't see that you've already found this (in one of your comments).  What *kind* of warnings are you trying to get rid of?  Things like dangerous use of "this" -- you'll get a ton of these in any external library?

Comment: Ya, mostly dangerous use of this.

Comment: To confirm, @suppress {checkTypes} doesn't prevent dangerous use of this warnings.

Comment: That's correct.  Dangerous use of "this" is **not** a type error, therefore it is not caught in type warnings.  It is a *potential error* caused by "namespace flattening" -- very similar to your other question.

Comment: I'd **strongly** urge you **not** to ignore "dangerous use of this" warnings.  80-90% of the time they refer to places that your code may break when the compiler flattens a namespace.  You need to get rid of **all** of them (by replacing "this" with the namespace itself).  See my edit for more details.

Comment: Thanks for @this -- that event exception was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a --warning_level option that you can use with ClosureCompiler.jar

VERBOSE, QUIET, DEFAULT are options.

You should compile the PhoneGap separately with QUIET.

Comment: I'd rather not compile it separately, since I use the compiler to compile everything down to a single file.

Comment: Yeah...sorry.  I see what our guy did... We had some libraries that were external from us.  We just concatenated those files together, and only did the compile and minify on our own libraries, and then concatenated all of that together.  It would be nice if the compiler could be verbosity-controlled at the file level.

Comment: This seems close (http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings#@suppress_Tags). But doesn't seem to have a "suppress everything" argument.