# Can I silence Closure Compiler warnings for external libraries?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

When I run the closure compiler, I get a bunch of warnings like this:

```
 [exec] jquery/3.2.1/dist/jquery.js:733: WARNING - Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used.
 [exec]     arr[ preferredDoc.childNodes.length ].nodeType;
 [exec]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I end up with about 30 warnings in my build, all from jquery and bootstrap.js

I'm handling my build using an Ant script. The call to the Closure Compiler looks like this:

```
<target name="build_scripts" description="Compile frontend scripts">
 <exec executable="${java.exec}" failonerror="true">
   <arg line="-client -d64 -jar ${closure.jar}"/>
   <arg line="--js ${src.dir}/assets/js/*.js"/>
   <arg line="--js ${src.dir}/assets/js/**/*.js"/>
   <arg line="--js ${weblib.dir}/jquery/3.2.1/dist/jquery.js"/>
   <arg line="--js ${weblib.dir}/bootstrap-sass/3.3.7/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"/>
   <arg line="--externs ${build.dir}/jquery-3.2.externs.js"/>
   <arg line="--dependency_mode=STRICT"/>
   <arg line="--entry_point ${src.dir}/assets/js/main.js"/>
   <arg line="--js_output_file ${out.js.dir}/main.js"/>
   <env key="JAVA_HOME" path="${java_home}"/>
 </exec>
</target>
```

I thought the point of the externs file was to get rid of warnings like this? The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434306/ignore-compiler-warning-from-one-file-in-google-closure) seem to suggest I'd need to manually change it in the external libraries.

I don't want to silence all warnings; just these from external libraries. Is that possible?

Comment: Theoretically you could intercept the messages and filter out the ones that match. Parsing the output which, AFAIK, does not have XML or JSON would be interesting, but I'm sure someone's done it... Additionally, your final build message "warning count" would be different from what was outputted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--hide_warnings_for='path/segment'` flag should do what you need.